# Pass array into ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/u0jzkye1/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="send()">
    Send
    </button>
</div>
```

When the button is not within ng-repeat, how can I pass my item's id into ng-click function?

Comment: Which id do you need to send via click? If it is dynamic, then you will have to bind it within the ng-repeat itself. Else you could pass it as static value.

Answer (score 1):

Well `items` is already on `$scope` as you're using it in your `ng-repeat`. So you should simply be able to `ng-click="send(items)"`

Comment: this is fully correct. in fact, events dealing with states preserved on controller scope have little need of receive arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "one"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "two"
}];

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = items;

  $scope.send = function() {
    //get items' id
    $scope.items.forEach(function(item){
      alert(item.id);
    }, this);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="send()">
    Send
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I know forEach, but what's the `this` for?

Comment: @Jennifer  It is `thisArg` parameter, It  is provided to `forEach()`, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its `this` value.

Comment: @Jennifer Read the doc from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach